# Dynamic LINQ query - passing string issue

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a column named Rule in DB for storing one line of c# code, I want to retrieve them to.net program. The problem is, the retrieved line by lambda expression is not recognizable by .net program because of the c# class name in it. So is that the dynamical linq limit which can't implement it or not?

Expample 1:
Retrieved string from DB:

```
Regex.IsMatch(string.Concat(fieldValue1.Where(q => !Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Contains(q))), @"\d{11}")
```

Lambda Expr consuming the above retrieved string:

```
var result = fieldInfo.Where(RetrievedstringfromDB, Value)
```

The error is

> No property or field 'Regex' exists in type 'XXX'

The closest thing I found that would do that is using Roslyn to run the whole thing dynamically, but to be fair that might not a good workaround for the project I am working on now, any lights/thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: You are missing double quotes.  From : \d{11} To : @"\d{11}"

Comment: you are so right, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: What happens when you replace `RetrievedstringfromDB` with a literal example string?

Comment: There is no problem coming up with literal string, it's just when I planning to make that string as executable c# code, it started to pop up the error above, it's either 'regex' not recognizable or 'q' or 'Path'... Is that one of the limits Sysytem.linq.dynamical has?